# How do I make FilesMatch NOT blocking certain things?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache2

FilesMatch is blocking certain things it should not. I have the following config:

```
<FilesMatch "^.*$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch ".+\.(html?|cgi|shtml|phtml|js|php|css|[Jj][Pp][Ee]?[Gg]|[Gg][Ii][Ff]|[Pp][Nn][Gg]|ico|xml|wsdl)$">
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Satisfy Any
</FilesMatch>
```

But when I use this, I cannot access:

```
www.example.com/example/
www.example.com/example/?hello
```

I thought FilesMatch only operated on files. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

What I'm trying to achieve is to fulfill requirement 5.11 in the Cisecurity benchmark for Apache http server 2.2. It can be found here: https://www.cisecurity.org/cis-benchmarks/

From the document:

> **Description:**
>
> Restrict access to inappropriate file extensions that are not expected to be a legitimate part
>   of web sites using the FilesMatch directive.
>
> **Rationale:**
>
> ...
>
> **Audit:**
>
> Perform the following steps to determine if the recommended state is implemented:
>
> 1. Verify that the FilesMatch directive that denies access to all files is present as
>      shown in step 3 of the remediation with the Order of Deny, Allow.
> 2. Verify that there is another FilesMatch directive similar to the one in step 4 of the
>      remediation, with an expression that matches the approved file extensions.
>
> **Remediation:**
>
> Perform the following to implement the recommended state:
>
> 1. Compile a list of existing file extension on the web server. The following find/awk
>      command may be useful, but is likely to need some customization according to the
>      appropriate webroot directories for your web server. Please note that the find
>      command skips over any files without a dot (.) in the file name, as these are not
>      expected to be appropriate web content.
>
>    `find */htdocs -type f -name '*.*' | awk -F. '{print $NF }' | sort -u`
> 2. Review the list of existing file extensions, for appropriate content for the web
>      server, remove those that are inappropriate and add any additional file extensions
>      expected to be added to the web server in the near future.
> 3. Add the FilesMatch directive below which denies access to all files by default.
>
> `# Block all files by default, unless specifically allowed.`
>
> `<FilesMatch "^.*$">`
>
> `Require all denied`
>
> `</FilesMatch>`
>
> 4. Add another a FilesMatch directive that allows access to those file extensions
>      specifically allowed from the review process in step 2. An example FilesMatch
>      directive is below. The file extensions in the regular expression should match your approved list, and not necessarily the expression below.
>
> `# Allow files with specifically approved file extensions`
>
> `# Such as (css, htm; html; js; pdf; txt; xml; xsl; ...),`
>
> `# images (gif; ico; jpeg; jpg; png; ...), multimedia`
>
> `<FilesMatch "^.*\.(css|html?|js|pdf|txt|xml|xsl|gif|ico|jpe?g|png)$">`
>
> `Require all granted`
>
> `</FilesMatch>`

Of course, I had to modify "Require all granted" because I'm using Apache 2.2

Comment: try to remove the first one that blocks all files. if the default is deny all, everything except for your second FilesMatch would be blocked

Comment: Yes I know. That's the whole point. I want to block everything except what I specifically allow.

Comment: so you add the "order deny,allow". it should make the work

Answer (score 0):

This will deny access to all files except the files you specify in `FilesMatch` directive:

```
Order Allow,Deny
<FilesMatch ".*\.(html|php)$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```